# How do you sort a Python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python of scores that are integers. I want to sort them from lowest to highest. I have tried looking it up, but I find that I don’t understand what most of them mean. I have heard of sorted(), but I’m not sure how it works. How can I sort a list of numbers? Will sorted() help?

Comment: `sorted(scoreList)`

Comment: Any reason you can't use `sorted()`?

Comment: Maybe it's a homework assignment and they can't use `sorted()`?

Comment: If it is a homework question (or just an exercise), you should look into [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), they don't depend on the language. Otherwise, just use `sorted`. Also what is `scoreList`? A function that accepts a number (`w`) or a function (`all`)?

Comment: In Python, we don't use `()` to access list elements; we use `[]`. `all` is a built-in function, not a special index. Is it possible you're coming from a MATLAB background? Regardless of what language you worked in before, pretending Python acts like it is a recipe for disaster. The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is excellent. Read through it to cover the basics.

Comment: I didn't know sorted was a command thanks

Comment: @kevinkayaks how would I get the highest thing in the list?

Comment: @JustCoookie you can use the `max` function, e.g. `max(myList)`

Comment: I get this error @HenryWoody `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't like empty lists—you have to handle that case yourself since it might depend on context. You can just make a check before passing the list to `max`. If you know the default max value you want, you could do something like `max_val = max(myList) if len(myList) > 0 else 0` (using 0 as a default here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *sorted(scoreList)*.

Get the reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp).

Comment: Please, Being a little more descriptive with your answer. :)

Comment: The 'sorted()' function return sorted list of the given iterable(lists,tuple,strings) object. defaultly it's return ascending form you can change with "sorted(iterable, reverse=true)".  more, you refer in google :)

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your approach:

- You're not defining a `scoreList` variable *in the code you posted*. Maybe you want to pass it as parameter:

  ```py
  def sortList(scoreList):
  ```
- You access the index of a list using `[]`, and not `()`:

  ```py
  if scoreList[w] < scoreList[all]:
  ```
- You don't check if all elements are greater than an element using `[all]`. Instead, use the `all` function:

  ```py
  if all(scoreList[w] < element for element in scoreList):
  ```
- You assign a variable using `=`, and not `==`:

  ```py
  scoreList[w] = scoreList[1]
  ```

Your logic is also wrong, there are some basic algorithms you can look up if you want to do it by hand, such as [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) or [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Of course, there's always the [`sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `scoreList` is since you used brackets after it.
If it's a list it should be done as [].
Assuming `scoreList` is a list:

```py
scoreList = [3,5,67,83,555,38,22,1]
sortedList = []

for i in range(len(scoreList)):
    sortedList.append(max(scoreList))
    scoreList.remove(max(scoreList))

print(sortedList[::-1])
```

Remove [::-1] if you want in descending order.

This is of course you don't want to use `scoreList.sort()`